# saving a filename with an extension to an existing filename

Tags: python

I would like to save a file by adding an extension to the existing filename, by extension I do not mean change .csv to .HTML.
What I mean is if I have an existing file file1.csv
I would like to save the other file as file1_processed.csv.

I tried doing this

```
data = pd.read_csv("file1.csv")
df = x
df.to_csv(os.path.basename(data) + '_' + 'processed' + '.csv')
```

however, it gives an error

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DataFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filename = "file1"
data = pd.read_csv(filename + ".csv")
# ...
df.to_csv(filename + '_processed.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` has contents of file `file1.csv`, not the file name. You need to assign the file name to a variable if the name of the file is not same always.

```
file_name = "file1.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(file_name )
df = x
name, extension = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_name))
df.to_csv(name + '_' + 'processed' + extension)
```